# How do I update to Ubuntu 12.04 if update manager doesn't prompt it?

Tags: 12.04, update-manager, release-upgrade

I was updating to Ubuntu 12.04 and I lost my wireless connection. I turned off my computer and got to a better connection and now my "Update Manager" does not prompt for the upgrade.

Comment: You were in the middle of the upgrade process?

Comment: Yes, it had already started downloading for at least an hour...

Comment: What is the output of `lsb_release -a`?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that all possible updates are installed using update-manager.

After that you can trigger the update-manager with the dist-upgrade option which should start it showing the upgrade option to 12.04.
Do it like this:

1. Press Alt+F2
2. Type "update-manager --dist-upgrade" and press enter

If that doesn't work it might be that all your repositories are already changed to the new distribution. You just need to finalize the installation:

1. Press Alt+F2
2. Type "gnome-terminal" and press enter
3. In the terminal window type "sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade"
4. Enter your password when prompted
5. Accept the proposed update

Please let us know if one of these ways worked for you.

Comment: When I tried it the first way, it says "Your system is up to date"

When I tried it the second way it just said 0 upgraded.

What happened was it was partially installed and when my internet connection got lost, it said it would save what had been upgraded so far.

Answer (score -1):

Try `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`; if your system is fully updated before you type that, it SHOULD upgrade to the newer version.

Uh, good luck; this usually works, but not every time.

Comment: no, `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` does not upgrade Ubuntu to a higher version. See http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/apt-get.8.html